# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCoreLocation.dyli

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa, cocoapods

My project was running good and well. Then, I installed cocoa pods in order to integrate the google maps framework. I installed cocoa pods and then installed the google framework using the same. But, now when I'm running my project I'm getting the following error :

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/easiembedded/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/25C02CA6-00E1-49BF-BF48-215894699255/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EBD97186-C4C1-46F1-9BB0-E68F1082A0AC/Sample.app/Sample
>   Reason: image not found

PS :

1. I already have "@executable_path/Frameworks" value added to my "Runpath Search Paths" in the build settings
2. I have tried by adding the "CoreLocation" framework to "Embedded Binaries" and "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"

I'm totally stuck with this. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: check `Embedded content contains swift code` build setting

Comment: Thank You for your response! Have updated how I got rid of the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the issue occurred.

But the next fresh day, I just came and tried removing the cocoa pods from project and I deleted all the related pod files. Then, just to give the srvv's answer a try as "Embedded content contains swift code" in build settings is set to NO, I just did ctrl+Z in my project folder and the project, to restore all the pod related files again. And, then run the "pod install" command in the terminal to install the pod again.

And, the project runs properly. And, no need of setting the "Embedded content contains swift code" as YES.

What I guess is, I did some mistake probably while installing the pods first time in my project.

Cheers!